# Language Translation is not working in liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

i created one sample portlet in liferay 6.2,in that i need to print the unicode value in french language.

I have created language_fr_FR.properties file in src folder and in my jsp page i have print the value.

```
results.noresults          = No r\u00E9sultats (language_fr_FR.prop)
```

jsp page

```
<liferay-ui:message key="results.noresults"/>
```

in jsp am getting the message like
No r�sultats

can anyone please tell me from which class or method this unicode translation is performing in liferay.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Liferay's language property files need to be encoded in UTF-8 instead of the otherwise typical Java encoding ISO-8859-1 (or escaped characters).

It's sometimes hard to convince your IDE that this is indeed the expected encoding, but it works.

Comment: thanks you...i created one method to parse unicode..now i want to know from where default parsing method is calling in PropertiesUtil.java class. in source code.

Comment: hi Olaf, can you please tell me from which class or method this unicode translation is performing in liferay...The below code is working fine so i want to override with this code...String string = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("Tout s \u00E9 lectionner/d \u00E9 lectionner" );

Comment: other than guessing it'd require an ext plugin to change this behavior, not from the top of my head. If you're going to create an ext plugin, you'll be doing an open heart surgery anyways and should be familiar with the code. Watch out for any class that starts with Language* and you should at least be close to where the property files are read. You'll need to understand quite a bit about the inner workings to create an ext anyway (read: I'd advise against doing so for this simple purpose. Just go with encoding or embrace some batch processing during build)

Comment: yes Olaf, i created one ext-plugin and i just added sop in each method of LanguageImpl.java,LanguageResources.java,LiferayResourceBundle.java and UnicodeLanguageImpl.java files under language package then LanguageFilter.java under filter.language package.but i am not getting any sop message from console.

Answer (score 0):

One way to be sure you have a correct properties file is writing in a xx.properties.native and, no matter its encoding, invoking native2ascii task at build time. That should result in a file with non-ascii characters encoded as Unicode.
If you want to write directly in xxx.properties with your regional characters you must ensure you use UTF-8 encoding, and IDEs don't do it automatically sometimes.
Liferay IDE uses UTF-8 for editing properties files in last versions, so you should be able to write just regular French in your properties files, and forget about translating into Unicode.
That's the theory anyway. I've had some headaches with this.

Comment: thanks you...i created one method to parse unicode..now i want to know from where default parsing method is calling in PropertiesUtil.java class. in source code.